# El script que cambia al otro formulario no abre

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una página que viene a ser un formulario de registro e inicio de sesión, en la parte donde necesito que cambie la vista al formulario de registro el script no funciona:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu li").on("click", function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $("#formularios form").hide();
    $("#formularios form").eq(i).show();
    $("#menu li a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).find("a").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #18A383;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

form {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

input,
textarea {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  width: 280px;
}

.field {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 240px;
}

.field:focus {
  border-color: #18A383;
}

.center-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.field-container div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.field-container i {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  color: #888;
  padding: 13px 10px 11px 10px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#menu,
#formularios {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 340px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

#menu ul li a {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.active {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.columns>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.columns .field {
  width: 80px;
}

#form-register {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.btn-green {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3CC93F;
}

.btn-black {
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: #222;
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #37B839;
}

.btn-green:active {
  background-color: #29962A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Registrarse</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="formularios">
  <form action="">
    <p>Correo electrónico:</p>
    <div class="field-container">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i>
      <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="user@example.com"> <br/>
    </div>

    <p>Contraseña:</p>
    <div class="field-container">
      <i class="fa fa-key fa-lg"></i>
      <input type="password" class="field" placeholder="*******">         <br/>
    </div>

    <p class="center-content">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green" value="Iniciar sesión">
    </p>
  </form>

  <form action="" id="form-register">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="field-container">
        <p>Nombre:</p>
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-lg"></i>
        <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Marcos">
        <br/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-container">
        <p>Apellido:</p>
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-lg"></i>
        <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Rivas"> <br/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Correo electrónico:</p>
    <div class="field-container">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="user@example.com">
      <br/>
    </div>

    <p>Contraseña:</p>
    <div class="field-container">
      <i class="fa fa-key fa-lg"></i>
      <input type="password" class="field" placeholder="********">         <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="columns">
      <div class="field-container">
        <p>Compañía:</p>
        <i class="fa fa-building fa-lg"></i>
        <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Microsoft">           <br/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-container">
        <p>Teléfono:</p>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
        <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="+52 1 5523">           <br/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="center-content">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green" value="Iniciar sesión">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: La direccion a la que se dirige el script es una libreria jQuery? Soy nuevo en esto de javascript

Comment: El cambio aquí si funciona (Inicio/Registro).... tienes la librería de jQuery insertada en tu código?

Comment: Ya tengo el src que me lleva a un jquery (externo) que me hace funcionar el programa, pero ahora las validaciones que tengo dentro del codigo no funcionan.